# Should I include original datatables css when using Bootstrap theme?

Tags: datatables

Following https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html, it doesn't include the original datatables css.

If I remove the script in the source:
(From the comment it reads like not important?)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // For demo to fit into DataTables site builder...
    $('#example')
        .removeClass( 'display' )
        .addClass('table table-striped table-bordered');
</script>
```

There will be no styling to the table, see https://jsfiddle.net/gLrf9o8t/

It appears that the demo is cheating... Does it mean all datatables style classes become useless if I don't include the original css file?

However if I include the orginal css back in, the paging bar looks very weird, see https://jsfiddle.net/r45f6dt6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the DataTables.Bootstrap CSS, you also need to manually apply Bootstrap classes to the table. You cannot change those classes after DataTables has been initialized as you are with the script above because they will not be applied to the DataTables grid. If you must change classes programmatically, init DataTables as a callback on that function.

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ... >
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r45f6dt6/1/)**

Note that I've removed the base DataTables CSS link.